# ColdFusion ORM relationship mapping 'one-to-many' issue when mapped to subclass

Tags: orm, coldfusion

This is repeatable and may be a bug. For this example I have three tables:

**Payment**
paymentID
date
paymentType

**Credit**
paymentID
cardNo
cardTypeID

**CardType**
ID
Description

Payment and Credit are parent and subclass tables respectively. The code is as follows:

**payment.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="payment" discriminatorcolumn="paymentType"{
    property name="paymentID";  
    property name="date";
}
```

**credit.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" extends="payment" joincolumn="paymentID"  
    table="credit" discriminatorvalue="ccard"{
    property name="cardNo";  
    property name="cardTypes" fieldtype="many-to-one" lazy="true" cfc="cardType"
        fkcolumn="cardTypeID";
}
```

**cardType.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="cardType"{
    property name="id";
    property name="description";
    property name="creditCards" fieldtype="one-to-many" lazy="extra" 
        type="struct" structkeycolumn="id" cfc="credit" fkcolumn="cardType";
}
```

The error lay with the "one-to-many" relationship off of cardType.cfc. When ORM generates the SQL, it tries to apply the fkcolumn to the select and where clauses to the parent class:

```
select
    creditcard0_.cardType as cardType30569_1_,
    creditcard0_.PaymentID as PaymentID1_,
    creditcard0_.PaymentID as PaymentID30570_0_,
    creditcard0_.Date as Date30570_0_,
    creditcard0_1_.cardNo as cardNo30572_0_,
    creditcard0_1_.cardType as cardType30572_0_ 
from
    Payment creditcard0_ 
inner join
    CreditCardPayment creditcard0_1_ 
      on creditcard0_.PaymentID=creditcard0_1_.PaymentID 
where
    creditcard0_.cardType=?
```

This causes a lot of "CardType does not exist" errors when a simple entityload("cardType") is called.

Anyone have any idea why it would not apply it correctly to the child class and is it possibly a configuration setting I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, If I map the hbmxml file like so, apparently it fixes the issue:

```
<map lazy="extra" name="creditCards" table="CreditCardPayment" inverse="true">
    <key column="cardType"/>
    <map-key column="CardNo" type="string"/>
    <many-to-many unique="true" column="PaymentID" class="cfc:entities.credit"/>
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding mapedSuperClass="true" to the Payment CFC. Not sure if this will work as typically I have used mappedSuperClass for non persistent 'base' objects.

Comment: Can you make a non-persistent 'base' class and have payment and credit objects extend that?

Comment: Not if I want to continue using it as an inherited object with a discriminator column which is the desire. If I turn the persistence off, CF returns a null value error as the parent class is no longer a loaded entity.